# Best practices with mongodb and expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to know how to handle mongo connections with express.

My questions are:

Is it a good idea create a middleware to handle every request and before execute it, connect to mongo?

Is it a good idea create a middleware to handle every request and after make response, close mongo connection?

Comment: What is the point? What issue are you trying to solve? Of course those are bad ideas. If you hit the limit of connections, you can opt for a connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to call `mongoose.connect` during your application's startup and just leave it open. That call creates a connection pool that is shared across all Mongoose models, by default.

The default pool size is 5, but you can tweak that in your call's [options](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options):

```
const options = {
    poolSize: 10
};
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', options);
```

Comment: Can you give a small example for better understanding, it will be helpful.

Comment: and whats about security?